# setInterval Causing Browser to Crash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs:

```
<div class="heading-bold"></div>
<div class="heading-raise"></div>
<div class="heading-isis"></div>
```

I want these to appear and then fade out, in sequence, with a timed delay between each one. I then need the process to repeat on an infinite loop. I've put together a rather crude method which does work however adding `setInterval` in order to loop the sequence causes the browser to eventually crash.

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    animate();
}

function animate() {
    window.setInterval(animate, 9500);

    var delay = 1000;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-bold').css({
            "display": "block"
        });
    }, delay);

    var delay = 3000;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-bold').fadeOut(750);
    }, delay);

    var delay = 3750;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-bold').remove(750);
    }, delay);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-raise').css({
            "display": "block"
        });
    }, delay);

    var delay = 5750;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-raise').fadeOut(750);
    }, delay);

    var delay = 6250;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-raise').remove(750);
    }, delay);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-isis').css({
            "display": "block"
        });
    }, delay);

    var delay = 8750;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-isis').fadeOut(750);
    }, delay);

    var delay = 9500;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.heading-isis').remove(750);
    }, delay);
}
```

I'm sure there's a much more efficient way of doing this however I was wondering if there's any simple solution to stop this from crashing the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
function animate () {
    window.setInterval(animate, 9500);
```

Every time the `animate` function runs, it starts an interval timer to call it again.  That means the first time it runs, it will run once in 9500 ms.  The second time it runs, it starts *another* interval timer, so after 9500ms it will run *twice*.  Then 4 times. Then 8... etc.

You either want to change that `setInterval` to `setTimeout` so it only runs once after those 9500ms (then queueing itself up again with another call to `setTimeout`), or move the call to `setInterval`:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    animate();
    setInterval(animate, 9500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks James and Matthew. Moving setInterval as suggested has resolved this and it does what I need for now. Time to get the books out and study though I reckon!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling

```
window.setInterval(animate, 9500);
```

Inside the animate function? You're setting an interval (infinitely) which retuns itself (infinitely) with each run, so it will take up exponentially more resources than needed.

Restrcture it like this;

```
function animate () {
    ...
}

window.onload = function start() {
    animate();
    window.setInterval(animate, 9500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe following will be suitable for you:

Edit: I added Infinite loop by making fadeIn() and fadeOut() call eachother on animation end.

```js
 var interval_ms = 1.5 * 1000;
 var fadeIn;
 var fadeOut;

 fadeIn =  function(){
  
      $( "#div1" ).fadeIn( interval_ms, 
        function() {
          $( "#div2" ).fadeIn( interval_ms, 
            function() {
              $( "#div3" ).fadeIn( interval_ms , fadeOut );
            }
          );
        }
      );
  
  };

fadeOut =  function(){
  
      $( "#div3" ).fadeOut( interval_ms, 
        function() {
          $( "#div2" ).fadeOut( interval_ms, 
            function() {
              $( "#div1" ).fadeOut( interval_ms , fadeIn );
            }
          );
        }
      );
  
  };

fadeIn();
```

```html
 

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div id="div1" class="heading-bold"  style="display: none;" > div1 </div>
    <div id="div2" class="heading-raise" style="display: none;" > div2 </div>
    <div id="div3" class="heading-isis"  style="display: none;" > div3 </div>
```